# How to get HTTP headers form data

Tags: javascript, http-headers, form-data

I am using an external payment site to redirect to my own website. I need some of the form data in the headers and I cannot figure out how to grab the data. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Headers]

Inside the headers tab, I want to get the information from the `Form Data` tab.

The code below is what I was able to find regarding getting headers, but the problem is it only grabs the code from the `ResponseHeaders` tab. And `req` does not have any function to get the form data.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
```

I want to see if there is a function where I can do something like

```
var formData = req.getFormData().toLowerCase();
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain (although prepared to learn) that we can only **send** `form data`, not `"GET"` it in a response. Am I confused?

Comment: the formdata is not passed in by me. It is from a Paypal payment redirect, and I was unable to figure out how to set a custom redirect url through paypal, and I saw that the data I need is included in FormData on the redirect, so I just wanted to see if it is possible get access to it

Comment: Ah, PP are sending it in their (redirect) request to your server? I think I probably am confused. I'll be quiet now. Good luck. EDIT: What Quentin says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way, in browser-side JavaScript, to get information about the request that was used to get the current page from the server.

If you want access to it, you'll need to use server side code to dynamically generate the page and include it in the DOM (perhaps as a JavaScript object in a `<script>` element, or as a `data-*` attribute, or in `<meta>` elements) and then use JS to extract it from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The mozilla site provides an example (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getResponseHeader)

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open("GET", "unicorns-are-teh-awesome.txt", true);
client.send();
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(this.readyState == this.HEADERS_RECEIVED) {
    console.log(client.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"));
  }
}
```

But fetch is nicer (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/headers):

```
fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.headers); // returns a Headers{} object
  response.blob().then(function(myBlob) {
    var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
    myImage.src = objectURL;
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I was looking for. I can get the ResponseHeaders. I am looking for the formData that comes as part of the response.